# C# WPF Get Selected Combobox Binding Fields

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a combo box that has a data template with 3 fields bound from a data table.

The problem I have is I want to find out which item I have selected in the combobox and get access to one of the bound fields.
The SelectedIndex gives me the position but I want the id so I can pass that directly to the Insert method.

You can see below I have 3 fields on for each combo box item.
I would like to identify the primary key for the selected item, "uid"

```
     <ComboBox Name="cboCombo" Width="300" Height="42" TabIndex="3"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxKey}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   
                          SelectedValuePath="uid"
                      FontSize="12"/>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxKey}"">
            <Grid Height="35" Width="300" ShowGridLines="false">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding uid
                    Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding field_1}"
                    Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding field_2}"
                    Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You could bind selectedvalue to some public property in your datacontext. SelectedValue="{Binding SomeProperty}"

Answer (score 0):

I think i've got it:

```
DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)cboComboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Comment: Well, yes, if you're storing `DataRow` objects in the dropdown list.  That wouldn't be my first choice, though.

Comment: It also requires code-behind. Why do all that when you can simply bind `SelectedItem` to a strongly-typed property in your View Model?